# socket in nodejs will not close no matter what

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make a script that will connect a bot to a kahoot. However I can only use a certain name one time otherwise I will get a duplicate name error, even after closing all sockets, terminating sockets, removing listeners, etc. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: added the cleanup on process end that still doesn't work

```
var Kahoot = require("kahoot.js-latest");
var colors = require('colors');

var bot = new Kahoot;

function cleanup() {
    bot.leave();
    bot.removeAllListeners();
    bot.socket.close();
    bot.socket.terminate();
}

bot.join(process.argv[2], "a")
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Joining...".cyan);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        cleanup();
    });

[`exit`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `SIGTERM`].forEach((eventType) => {
    process.on(eventType, (code) => {
        for (n in bots) {
            cleanup();
        }
        console.log("Exiting Process with code: ".yellow + code);
    })
})
```

After terminating the process and trying to run it again with the same name, I get a duplicate name error even though surely that connection should be destroyed by now

Edit: the error:

```
{
  description: 'Duplicate name',
  type: 'loginResponse',
  error: 'USER_INPUT'
}
```

Comment: add error to topic!!!

Comment: why do you need to duplicate 
-> 
var bot = new Kahoot; ???

Comment: also that duplication was just a mistake imma remove itr

Comment: sockets haven't closed because of duplicate

Comment: it still doesn't close without the duplicate, also my actual code doesn't have that it was just a mistakein the post

Comment: It looks like you're only disconnecting when there's an error, does the catch clause ever execute?

Comment: `.catch` only executes when the promise throws or rejects, and that's the only place you're calling `cleanup()`, so `cleanup()` only executes if you fail to connect, which is sort of counter intuitive.

Comment: making it cleanup on process exit also does not work either. the sockets just don't close

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kahoot.js-latest seems badly maintained, the link to the documentation leads nowhere.

Comment: I don't know kahoot, but `{
  description: 'Duplicate name',
  type: 'loginResponse',
  error: 'USER_INPUT'
}` looks very much like you cannot join the same kahoot with the same name twice. This is an API error, it has nothing to do with the sockets not closing - they usually are getting forcibly closed by the operating system when your application terminates.

Comment: that's true, but even after ending the script and stuff it doesn't work still? I can never use the name again unless I restart my computer or something

Comment: I dont know about the error, but what variable is bots????
and use next cleanup call -> cleanup(bot), and add bot argument to function -> function cleanup(bot) {...your code

Comment: for (bot in bots) {
            cleanup(bot);
}

but still question is - what variable is bots?!

Comment: https://replit.com/@MiroslavGrabins/AwareHighAngle#index.js